# Portable way to check the presence of non-portable integral types

Tags: c++

I would like to profit by int64_t for my int, when present in a c++98 or greater implementation (I know C++11 already provides a 64-bit int).
Is there a portable and generic way to check the presence of int64_t or - even better - any 64-bit-or-greater integer type available, as in:

```
#ifdef has_int64_t
typedef int64_t myint
#else
typedef int myint
#endif

//...code
myint a;
```

If possible the check should work for c++98, c++03 and c++11.

Comment: Accept more answers, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure this should work using stdint.h:

```
#ifdef INT64_C
//...
#else
//...
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

The situation with `stdint.h` and the C++11 `cstdint` headers is rather tricky. Especially since they are missing on certain VS versions. The easiest route is certainly [boost stdint](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/integer/doc/html/boost_integer/cstdint.html).